# Create a nested fields and store dataframe to MongoDB using scala?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I'm working with Scala, I have a problem to map data from HBase to store in MongoDB. Let me explain:

I have a Person and Address Tables in Hbase, One person for many address.

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

val dfPerson = sparkSession.read.format()...

dfPerson.show():

+---------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+---------+
|PERSON_ID|           LAST_NAME|          FIRST_NAME|COUNTRY|     CITY|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+---------+
|     1005|               Miley|                John|  Spain|   Madrid|
|     1005|               Miley|                John|  Spain|Barcele..|
|     1009|              Rodney|              Justin| France|    Paris|
|     1009|              Rodney|              Justin| France|  Creteil|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------+
```

I need to map these data in nested object format, then it will be stored in MongoDB, there a colleccion has arrays address block inside it, as like:

```
[ {
    name: "John"
    lasteName: "Miley"
    address:[
      {city: "Bacelona", country: "Spain", ... },
      {city: "Madrid", country: "Spain", ...},
       ...
    ]
    },
   {  
    name: "Justin"
    lasteName: "Rodney",
    address: [..]
  }
]
```

Are there any framework to map these escanrie?

thanks your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1005", "Miley", "John", "Spain", "Barceleona"),
  ("1009", "Rodney", "Justin", "France", "Paris"),
  ("1009", "Rodney", "Justin", "France", "Creteil")
).toDF("PERSON_ID", "LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME", "COUNTRY", "CITY")

//New column names 
val newCols = List("id", "lastName", "name", "country", "city")

//rename all columns and groupby to create nested address  
val resultDF = df.select(df.columns.zip(newCols).map(c => col(c._1).as(c._2)):_*)
  .groupBy("id", "name", "lastName")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"city", $"country")).as("address"))
```

Final Schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is the final schema that you want. To store to mongoDB you can use `mongo-spark-connector"` https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/scala-api/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shankar Koirala,  It's work.  Only it takes a little time.